# Format double/decimal value in MVC 3 Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, format

I really cannot figure out ***how to format double/decimal value*** like that

**12,123,123.78**

Here is my html

```
@grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "grid",
        headerStyle: "head",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        columns: grid.Columns(
                            grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Candy Bar", "Products", new { id = item.ChainID })),
                                       grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Per Capita", "ProductsByCategory", new { id = item.ChainID })),
                                 grid.Column("CinemaName", "Complejo"),
                                              grid.Column("TotalSum2", "Monto").Format(  ???? )
)
```

---

If I do this

```
grid.Column("TotalSum2", "Monto", format: (item) => item.TotalSum2.ToString("0:C"))
```

I get this:

**270223:C**

and this

```
"{0:n0}"
```

gives

**{27022:n3}**

---

SOLUTION:

```
grid.Column("TotalSum2", "Monto", format: (item) => item.TotalSum2.ToString("#,0.00"))
```

Comment: Just making sure you want "." and not commas in the first parts? 12.123.123,78 not 12,123,123.78?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [CultureInfo and format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

```
grid.Column("TotalSum2", "Monto", format: (item) => item.TotalSum2.ToString("#,#"))
```

Comment: But what I have to write inside of Format(???) It says that it should be dynamic object and etc...

Answer (score 1):

Set a proper `CultureInfo` on the current thread or use `DisplayFormatAttribute`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx

Comment: But what I have to write inside of Format(???) It says that it should be dynamic object and etc...

Comment: Nothing - use `DisplayFormatAttribute` instead

Comment: I don't have that method. I have only Format()

Comment: Click on the link that I posted. Read the documentation. It's an *attribute*.

Comment: Good point, you can add the [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:#,#}")] attribute to the TotalSum2 property.

Comment: Also the suggestion from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx result = d1.ToString("#,0.00"); //result = "1,234.56"  Doesn't work at all... grid.Column("TotalSum2", "Monto", format: (item) => item.TotalSum2.ToString("#,0.00"))   I cannot see "," separator

Comment: Also I used it  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,0.00}")]   but no visible changes... :(